# Strange behavior of QColorDialog, when called from QStyledItemDelegate subclass

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

in the course of examining a different problem with lifetime issues on item delegate editors in a more complex [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299616/calling-qcolordialog-triggered-from-qstyleditemdelegate-editor-results-in-crash), I stumbled upon a strange behavior of QColorDialog, when called from a QStyledItemDelegate subclass.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor,QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QColorDialog,
    QGridLayout, QStyledItemDelegate, QTableView, QWidget
)


class ItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            return QColorDialog(parent)
            #return QColorDialog(parent.parent())
            #return QColorDialog()
        else:
            return super(ItemDelegate, self).createEditor(parent, option, index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
            color = QColor(value)
            editor.setCurrentColor(color)
            editor.show()
        else:
            super(ItemDelegate, self).setEditorData(editor, index)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            color = editor.currentColor()
            model.setData(index, color, Qt.EditRole)
        else:
            super(ItemDelegate, self).setModelData(editor, model, index)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        if index.column() == 1:
            pass
        else:
            super(ItemDelegate, self).updateEditorGeometry(editor, option, index)


class ColorItem(QStandardItem):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super(ColorItem, self).__init__()
        self.setData(color)

    def setData(self, value, role = Qt.EditRole):
        if role == Qt.EditRole and isinstance(value, QColor):
            super(ColorItem, self).setData(value, Qt.DecorationRole)
        super(ColorItem, self).setData(value, role)

    def type(self):
        return QStandardItem.UserType + 234


class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Item Delegate")

        data = [
            # label, rgb
            [ 'color', (0, 139, 139)],
            [ 'color', (255, 215, 0)],
        ]

        # create model, view, and delegate
        self.model = model = QStandardItemModel(len(data), 2)
        tableView = QTableView()
        tableView.setModel(model)
        delegate = ItemDelegate()
        tableView.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        tableView.setEditTriggers(
            QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed |
            QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked |
            QAbstractItemView.SelectedClicked)

        # fill model with data
        for row, (label, rgb) in enumerate(data):
            # column 0
            model.setItem(row, 0, QStandardItem(label))
            # column 1
            model.setItem(row, 1, ColorItem(QColor(*rgb)))
            #index = model.index(row, 1, QModelIndex())
            #tableView.openPersistentEditor(index)

        # finalize window
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(tableView, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resize(400, 200)

    def result(self):
        model = self.model
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            label = model.item(row, 0).data(Qt.EditRole)
            value = model.item(row, 1).data(Qt.EditRole)
            print('[%s] %s: %s' % (row, label, value.getRgb()[:3]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    window.result()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

When executing this script, double clicking on a color item displays the standard QColorDialog. The dialog will close immediately, if it is moved. OTOH, if selecting an arbitrary color beforehand, the dialog is movable.

An explanation of this behavior is desired.

This lifetime issue is related to the underlying QStyledItemDelegate widget. A focus change on the table view might result in destruction of the created editor widget, but why makes selecting a color a difference? I've experimented with different parents for QColorDialog, but behavior persists, so it smells like an issue, internal to the dialog itself.

```
Environment:
Python: 3.4.5
Sip: 4.19.2
Qt5: 5.8.0
PyQt5: 5.8.2
Linux: openSUSE/KDE4
```